# Laravel-8 Insert multiple selection values into multiple records in database?

Tags: php, laravel-8

So I'm trying to create a room booking system where customer can create an order and select multiple room they want to book.

Right now I have 2 table:
Order(order_id, customer_name, etc...)
OrderDetail (id, order_id, room_number)

What I want to do is when an order is created it will insert all the rooms have been selected into OrderDetail table as separate record with the order_id of the order just been created.

My code:
Order.php
`

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Order";
    protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';
    public function Details() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class, 'order_id');
    }
}
```

`

OrderDetail.php
`

```
class OrderDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = "OrderDetail";
    public function FromOrder() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

`

OrderController.php
`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 $Order = new Order();
 $Order->customer_name = $request->input('customer_name');
 etc...
 $Order->save();
}
```

`

My selection input:
`

```
<select class="custom-select form-control-border id="roomnumber" name="roomnumber[]" multiple>
                            @foreach($Room as $key => $item)
                            <option class="item-{{$item->id}}" value="{{$item->room_number}}">{{$item->room_number}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

`